# How to print a number greater than 7 digits using poi(2.5) from excel sheet in the console using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

while retrieving the value it is giving in the exponential format for big numbers.

```
while (cells.hasNext ())
{
HSSFCell cell = cells.next ();

System.out.println ("Cell No.: " + cell.getCellNum ());

/*
 * Now we will get the cell type and display the values
 * accordingly.
 */
switch (cell.getCellType ())
{
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC :
 {

  // cell type numeric.
  System.out.println ("Numeric value: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());


  break;
 }
```

it is giving values for the numbers whose digit are greater than 7eg.(12345678) as in exponential.Can u help me to get the value in the same format.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is to use a [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29):

```
System.out.println("Numeric value: " + new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use an instance of [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000000");
System.out.print(df.format(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
```

Answer (score 3):

In package `org.apache.poi.ss.util` is class `NumberToTextConverter` with static member `toText`, which can help to represent any number value as string. For example:

```
String value = NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue());
```

P.S. I know that since that moment when the question has been asked, there have passed nearly 5 years. But nevertheless I hope that my decision will help someone